# How to fetch by page limit in RxCoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to fetch data by limit (pagination) in RxCoreData. But I cannot find documentation in RxCoreData Community. But I find the solution in coreData (not in RxCoreData) like:

```
let pageSize = 20 // Number of items per page
let pageNumber = 2 // Page number (0-based index)

let request: NSFetchRequest<YourEntity> = YourEntity.fetchRequest()
request.fetchLimit = pageSize
request.fetchOffset = pageSize * pageNumber

let fetchedResults = context.rx.entities(fetchRequest: request)
```

I tried some of the solution on StackOverFlow.

Comment: And what does not work with your solution? Errors?

Comment: I want to fetch the data by limit (pagination) like the example code above. But there is no solution and examples on any other websites or document.